# File copy access denied

Tags: java, file

Here I am trying to copy a file one location to another. I am having the source address as

```
F:\C#\Studies\OS\ch4.ppt
```

where I want to copy ch3.ppt to another location where user chooses .ie., fetching the destination address from the JFilechooser(Where ever the user wants to copy). Here I am getting access denied error

```
    {
        //Getting the value of fileLocationSourceDrive from table.
        //fileLocationSourceDrive contains F:\C#\Studies\OS\ch4.ppt

        JFileChooser location = new JFileChooser();
        location.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        location.showSaveDialog(null);
        String fileLocationDestination = location.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString();
        copyFile(fileLocationSourceDrive, fileLocationDestination);
    }


    public static void copyFile(String sourceFileName, String destionFileName) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Reading..." + sourceFileName);
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileName);
            File destinationFile = new File(destionFileName);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, destinationFile);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
            //OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Sagar Ch\\Documents\\New folder");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Copied: " + sourceFileName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here the error block(Getting access denied)

```
Reading...F:\C#\Studies\OS\ch4.ppt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Sagar Ch\Documents\New folder (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at main.copyFile(main.java:1277)
at main$22.actionPerformed(main.java:1127)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you are trying to write the file (copy it, rather) onto the path of `C:\Users\Sagar Ch\Documents\New folder`, and that is not a "file", that's an existing folder. You should copy `ch4.ppt` to `C:\Users\Sagar Ch\Documents\New folder\ch4.ppt`.

Comment: Oh! Your right! I am trying to send the location to copyFile() function instead of sending the file. But how do I point copyFile() function to its destination address and then send the file which is to be copied

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(destinationFile + File.seperator + nameOfFileYoureCopying)` should work if you can get the name of the file you're copying.

Comment: Thanks EpicPandaForce!!! Made silly mistake in huge way! And thanks for the qiuck response too